# Get cert & key for python signxml from a PKS file

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, xml-signature, xmlsec

I used following command to get cert & key from a pks file.

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in ../my.pfx  -nocerts -out my.key
openssl pkcs12 -in ~/my.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem
```

However I keep getting error. I suspect **my.key** is not correct. How to generate the correct key and cert to feed signxml? I use python3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you in advance!

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/signxml/__init__.py", line 362, in sign
    key = load_pem_private_key(key, password=passphrase, backend=default_backend())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/base.py", line 16, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1025, in load_pem_private_key
    password,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1218, in _load_key
    mem_bio = self._bytes_to_bio(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 454, in _bytes_to_bio
    data_ptr = self._ffi.from_buffer(data)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of a unicode object
```

The sample code from xml page:

```
cert = open("example.pem").read()
key = open("example.key").read()
root = ElementTree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root).signed_xml
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is Python2 vs Python3 thing. All I needed is

```
key = open("example.key").read().encode('ascii')
```